# What's th mean by "public abstract class SampleAdapter <T extends Adapter> extends ViewGroup"?

Tags: java, android

I am not getting meaning by

```
public abstract class  SampleAdapter <T extends Adapter> extends ViewGroup
```

What does it do? In general we perform normal inheritance, but here something extended form.
can any body suggest me?

thanks

Comment: @thanks oil chaelrsworth for editing.

Answer (score 7):

This declares a class `SampleAdapter` that:

- has public visibility
- is [abstract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html); it cannot be instantiated directly; it must be be used as a base class.
- is [generic](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html); it must be parameterised by some type `T` that is a sub-class of `Adapter`.
- inherits from `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @oil charlesworth : thanks , can u please clear more your second point "is generic; it must be parameterised by some type T that is a sub-class of Adapter."

Comment: @Shubh: Follow the link in my answer!

Answer (score 2):

`T extends Adapter`:

The class `SampleAdapter` takes a class parameter `T` that **should** extend Adapter

**example**:

```
ArrayList A = new ArrayList<String>();
```

`String` is parameter for ArrayList.

```
SampleAdapter A = new SampleAdapter<parameterClass> ();
```

parameterClass is parameter for SampleAdapter (which is T) and it **must extend Adapter**:

```
public class parameterClass extends Adapter{//must extend Adapter
```

---

As for `abstract`, it says that class `SampleAdapter`is a class that can't be instantiated directly but rather must be extended by another class.

Comment: :what's mean by "class SampleAdapter takes a class parameter" ?

Comment: like `ArrayList A = new ArrayList<String>();` String is parameter for ArrayList... Now `SampleAdapter A = new SampleAdapter<parameterClass> ()` parameterClass is T and it must extend Adapter.. .I will add this to answer

Answer (score 1):

The thing inside the `< >` section is associated a concept called "generics". It's a feature introduced in Java from Java 5 and forward. You can read more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

`abstract` is referring to a class that can't be instantiated directly, usually because of some methods that need to be implemented in an extending class.

You'll have to implement those `abstract` methods in the subclass, otherwise your code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`abstract` means that the `SampleAdapter` class cannot have any objects, `<T extends Adapter>` means, that the `SampleAdapter` class is used as a container for objects of any class, that extends `Adapter`. Hope this helps.